Excel: удалить строки, если есть дубли в одной из ячеек этой строки в других строках?

В столбце A есть повторяющиеся значения, как друг за другом, так и разбросанные по столбцу, в столбце В сквозная нумерация. Как удалить строки в соответствии с найденными дублями в столбце А?

Вменяемо - никак, ибо задача недоопределена. Потому что нет критерия, какое из значений столбца В следует удалять, а какое сохранять.

Поэтому встроенная команда Excel "Remove Duplicates" просто оставляет первое попавшееся значение, а все последующие удаляет.

Data-->Data Tools--Remove Duplicates

Для иллюстрации, данные с удалёнными дублями помещены в другое место. Удаление производится на месте.


Если мой ответ помог, то вы можете отметить его как принятый.
